# Activiti deadlock occurs under JMeter performance test

Tags: spring, concurrency, deadlock, jmeter, activiti

I have a problem with **activiti concurrency**. We have a **wicket spring application** with **embedded activiti workflow engine**. It works fine without concurrent users, but during **jmeter performance test** activiti **creates deadlock** on its own tables. For example: ACT_RU_JOB, ACT_RU_EXECUTION, ACT_RU_VARIABLE. I have found a topic on activiti forum about this problem ( [Activiti Forum](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=682&start=0) ). They suggest using queues to start activiti processes. This solution didn't solve the problem, because deadlocks still occuring. I provide some configuration and stacktrace for you. All answers can be useful for me. Thanks for the help!

**my activiti configuration:**

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseType" value="mssql" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManagerLugy" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
        <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:/diagrams/idm/*.bpmn20.xml" />   
        <property name="history" value="none"/>     
        <property name="jdbcMaxActiveConnections" value="1000"/>
        <property name="jdbcMaxIdleConnections" value="10"/>
        <property name="jdbcMaxWaitTime" value="50000"/>
    </bean> 


    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>
```

**stacktrace:**

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableInstanceEntity.selectVariablesByExecutionId-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:471)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:355)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:535)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:495)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I removed all of the timers from my activiti diagram and deadlocks are disappeared. I don't know why, but it works.**

Answer (score 0):

I also had the dead lock problem when performing jmeter test.

In my case, the problem is that my DataSource pool is max 10 connections
but had 100 threads accessing the api that create a process instance which need to create an async task.

so if activiti use another connection(different from the connection to create a process instance) to create the async task, before returning the connection that create the process instance, then there may be a chance of deadlocking waiting for the connection(if all active connections are used for creating process instance)

When i set the pool size bigger than the jmeter thread count, the problem has gone.

--
My activiti version is 5.19.0